# Classifying singularities of $\frac{z^4 - 2z^2 + 1}{z^2 (z^2 + 4z + 1)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How are the singularities of $\frac{z^4 - 2z^2 + 1}{z^2 (z^2 + 4z + 1)}$ classified? I know that there are two ways of doing this, calculating the Laurent series or to use theorems behind zeroes and poles (calculating limits etc.). I'm not sure what should be applied here.

I believe the singularities are $z = 0, -2 + \sqrt{3}, -2 - \sqrt{3}$, by the quadratic formula.

Comment: You can apply the definitions of the different types of singularities directly (removable if it can be holomorphically extended, pole of order $m$ if the singularity of $(z-z_0)^m f(z)$ is removable, and essential if it's neither removable, nor a pole).

Comment: Directly in what sense? Could you possibly demonstrate that with one of the singularities? Should one factorize so that it becomes $\frac{z^4 - 2z^2 + 1}{z^2 (z - (-2 + \sqrt{3})) (z - (-2 - \sqrt{3}))}$?

Comment: For the pole $z=0$, notice that $(z-0)^2f(z)=z^2f(z)=\frac{z^4-2z^2+1}{z^2+4z+1}$, which can be holomorphically extended to $0$, so $(z-0)^2f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $0$, which means that by definition, $f$ has a pole of order 2 at 0.